# Is it risky to mount tmpfs volumes in Docker?

Tags: privilege-escalation, docker

Sometimes I need to run I/O intensive operations in memory. The **tmpfs** facility works really well for this, but I was wondering if there are any big risks of using tmpfs mounts inside a container. Can it be used to compromise the host?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, as `tmpfs` is a mature driver, and unless a strange bug appears (unlikely but possible), it's as risky as mounting an ext3 filesystem, or any network card, or loading any other driver.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a risk, depending on the kernel you use. By invalid data one could achieve a buffer overflow. If this happens the big question is what priviledges docker have. If you run it as root you have a serious problem. I am not up to date if this vulnurability is fixed or still an issue. Maybe someone else know this here. Otherwise take a look at the lkml and ask a core developer: https://lkml.org/

Comment: Could you be more specific? It sounds like you're referencing a specific vulnerability, but your explanation is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

The only security concern that comes into my mind is that the data of a tmpfs might be swapped by the host running the Docker daemon.